# Code injection vulnerability by echo-ing $_POST vars?

Tags: php, code-injection

I wonder if I have a code injection vulnerability below, in the fwrite ?

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {
    fwrite($fh, "\nPOST variable named " . $key . " has the value " . $val);
}
```

Should I sanitize the values somehow prior to writing them in the log file ?

UPDATE. fh is a log file handler

Comment: try htmlentities(); before or after (but only once) and use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: @Waygood: `htmlentities` is only appropriate for HTML output. `mysql_real_escape_string` is only appropriate when using the mysql extension, which shouldn't happen in new code as the mysql extension is outdated and being deprecated.

Comment: There was no specification of where the data would be used, so viewing in a browser was my initial thought (the same as Jon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no vulnerability as long as the logfile is treated by its consumers as plain text (which it should always be).

If you decide to output the unprocessed contents of the logfile as part of some HTML, then it would be a real vulnerability (probably of not very severe practical impact, but still). But the issue would be with the "other" code that displays text inside HTML without calling `htmlspecialchars`, not with this code here that simply writes the log.

Answer (score 3):

That would depend on what `$fh` is. If `$fh` is a HTML file, you can be in trouble. Not really if it is some text file or is inaccessible by any browser outside.

It is always a good idea to use `htmlspecialchars(..)` in case of HTML output.

**UPDATE**:

There is no problem as long as:

- your log file is elsewhere (outside public_html, basically inaccessible through a browser)
- Your webserver does not send a `text/html` header and treats it like a normal text file, if accessible

Comment: thank you, I am updating the question to mention fh it's a log file handler

Comment: "Not really if it is some text file or is inaccessible by any browser outside." that's interesting, so I should somehow put the log file in a hidden folder, or configure htaccess maybe.

Comment: As other have pointed out, its a problem **only** when the browser is able to access it, and it interprets it as HTML.

Answer (score 2):

This can be a source of reflected XSS (Cross-Site Scripting) attack (if you are writing to HTML file that is served to the user). You are not harmed by the attack, but some naive user will be.

Comment: Which reinforces the principle that all saved request variables should be sanitised.

Comment: @Pete: Sanitised how exactly? How would you do that without knowing how the log is going to be consumed?

Comment: @Jon: Good point. IMO, sanitization should be done in PHP if the consumer interpret the HTML and Javascript. Special sanitization has to be done by the program that consumes the log (if it is writing to log file).

Comment: @Jon - good point (and one I'll try to remember). In this case I guess that $fh handles a pretty innocent file that the programmer probably shares with no one else.